# Convert 1 to 01

Tags: java

I have an int between 1 - 99. How do I get it to always be a double digit, ie: 01, 04, 21?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yet another way

```
String text = (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
```

EDIT: The code is short enough that the JIT can compile it to nothing. ;)

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    for(int num=1;num<100;num++) {
        String text = (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
    }
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println(time/99/100000);
```

prints

```
0
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a -1, perfectly valid answer I'll even you out.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, not only that but your method is oodles faster. On a test using 1,000,000 random numbers from (0-100] using the same seed for each method and each one generating the numbers on their own your method has a avg time of 118 ns while the String.format method has an average time of 2666 ns. Downvote that!

Comment: String.format isn't very efficient. it is more flexible. You might find that alot of the 118 ns was spent creating the random numbers. (0 wasn't in the OP question btw) try 1-99 repeatedly.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I have no doubts that a lot of my time was done creating the numbers and I also had a printout that happened once every 100k iterations. I also realize that String.format is way more extendable than an int check (most of my college work was done in C printf ftw). I was just upset that you got down voted.

Answer (score 46):

Presumably you mean to store the number in a String.

Since JDK1.5 there has been the [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, which will let you do exactly what you want:

```
String s = String.format("%02d", someNumber);
```

One of the nice things about String.format() is that you can use it to build up more complex strings without resorting to lots of concatenation, resulting in much cleaner code.

```
String logMessage = String.format("Error processing record %d of %d: %s", recordNumber, maxRecords, error);
```

Answer (score 23):

Using

```
String.format("%02d", num)
```

Is probably the best option.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#NumberFormat()):

```
NumberFormat format = new NumberFormat();
format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
System.out.println(format.format(1));
```

**Note** - [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is a Java 5 method.

If you're using Java 5 or above you can do:

`String.format("%02d", 1);`

as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: that should be `"%02d"`, not `"%2d"`, otherwise you'll not get the leading zero.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
String.format("%02d", num)
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution:

```
String.valueOf(number + 100).substring(1);
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't say it was a *good* solution, just *a* solution :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by

```
String.format("%02d", 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it just using an int. You'll have to convert between Strings (for display) and back to ints (for calculations). You can use the [Java Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to format your Strings based on the input.

Answer (score 2):

I think, I should add the link to the official Java documentation on formatting numeric outputs.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Sample Snipplet: Prints 00 up to 100

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        System.out.println(String.format("%02d", i)); 
      }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00
01
...
10
...
100
```

Answer (score 1):

use number format 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use printf instead of String.format

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%02d%n",i);
    }
```

Comment: are u saying  
 System.out.format("%02d%n", i);

Comment: @nikhil2000 you can use either of them